# split apk's in productflavor

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way to split apk's to x86 x86_64 armv7 armv8 in product flavors?

```
productFlavors {
     a{
        dimension "engine"
        applicationId "xxxxx"

    }
    b{
        dimension "engine"
        applicationId "xxxx"

    }
```

Comment: x86_64 support both type

Answer (score 0):

You've to manually build app using different flavors. What i mean is that you've to build app using x86 once, then build using x86_64 and so on.

Comment: sounds spagetti

Comment: It is what it is, hoping to find a better way too.